# created serviceprovider then removed the file manually and am getting error

Tags: laravel

I created this provider:

> php artisan make:provider ShortcodesServiceProvider

I then had to delete the file, but am now getting

> FatalThrowableError in C:\xampp\htdocs\listagram\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\ProviderRepository.php line 146:
>
> Class 'App\Providers\ShortcodesServiceProvider' not found

How do I reset serviceproviders after manually deleting the provider file I created?

Comment: remove your `'App\Providers\ShortcodesServiceProvider` entry from `config/app.php`

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/8tVYZ1J.png  it is removed, still same error, also did run composer dump-autoload and same error remains

Comment: try `php artisan clear-compiled`

Comment: it was config cache, had to delete 2 cache files i the \bootstrap\cache

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should delete `bootstrap/cache/services.php` file manually and run `composer dumpauto` command to fix this.

Comment: did run composer dump-autoload and same error remains, also my app.php does not mention this service provider: http://i.imgur.com/8tVYZ1J.png

Comment: Try to delete `bootstrap/cache/services.php` file manually and run `composer dumpauto`

Comment: update your main answer with that information so I can select it as right answer :)

Comment: I just remove the 'App\Providers\ShortcodesServiceProvider' from the array in bootstrap/config.php file. Then solved my problem.